# Redirect page if no results from Firebase query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

I am using VueJS and Firebase to return results for users, this works correctly

```
export default{
 firebase() { 
  return{
    cSites: db.ref('users/').orderByChild('url').equalTo(this.$route.params.uid)
  }
 }
}
```

I am trying to work out how to redirect the app to another page if no results are returned but cant seem work out how. If tried with the readyCallback() function, but together with the existing firebase function did not work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The usage pattern [VueFire-usage](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire#usage) suggests a slightly different pattern. Did you try that one out?

Comment: I have tried this way, but need to put my Firebase query in a function as I am using this.$route.params.uid

Comment: I've not tested it, but perhaps `firebase: function () {` instead of `firebase() {`. Ref second section, headed 'If you need to access properties from the Vue instance, use the function syntax'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm extrapolating from the docs and the source code, maybe this will work for you

```js
firebase: function() {
  return {
    cSites: {
      source: db.ref('users/').orderByChild('url').equalTo(this.$route.params.uid),
      readyCallback: function () {
        if (!this.cSites) {
          this.$route.router.go('/');   // test and redirect here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note** when testing the 'function syntax', I get a warning in the console, but the result is ok.

> [Vue warn]: Invalid value for option "firebase": expected an Object, but got Function.

Ref [Github vuefire issue #133](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire/issues/133)

> It's a false alarm. You can use a function for the firebase property. The warning shouldn't appear.

For reference, `vuefire.js`

```js
function bind (vm, key, source) {
  var asObject = false
  var cancelCallback = null
  var readyCallback = null
  // check { source, asArray, cancelCallback } syntax
  if (isObject(source) && source.hasOwnProperty('source')) {
    asObject = source.asObject
    cancelCallback = source.cancelCallback
    readyCallback = source.readyCallback
    source = source.source
  }
```

To elaborate, cSites is the source object, with properties source and readyCallback.

Using the function syntax allows a kind of 'late binding', so that 'this' has a value at the time the function is called.

Comment: Guys, apologies for delayed response but have been caught up with a lot of things.

Basically what happens wit h this component is that i will load a users profile details if the user exists. If the query returns no results,that means the users does not exist and at that point i would want to perform another action.

So from my original code, if the user exists, everything works correctly, but i dont know how to check if the query returns no results.... I hope that makes it clearer... thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. So I followed your above example and it works to some extent... If I use:

`function: {
source: .....` it works, but it i can not use dynamic queries

if I use:
`firebase: function() {
 source: ...
 readyCallback: function() {...}` 
i get an error on the readyCallback saying Unexpected token, bit stumped... hopefully i can crack it today

Comment: If I read you correctly, you mean `function: { cSites: { source: db.ref...`? The 2nd syntax was one I found some weeks ago, but testing today it errors even before running, so I changed the example.

Comment: By dynamic queries, you mean `.equalTo(this.$route.params.uid)`? I haven't tried it - if it fails, it's a bug because see the vuefire source block, the two styles should resolve to the same code.

Comment: Actually the `firebase: function() {` syntax is the right one. It works, but you get a warning `[Vue warn]: Invalid value for option "firebase": expected an Object, but got Function.`

Comment: I get that error also, but that can be ignored... But my error points to the  `:` after the readyCallback

Comment: Missing a comma?

Comment: this is the error i get
`Unexpected token, expected ; (64:21)

  62 | 
  63 |         
> 64 |         readyCallback: function (){
     |                      ^`

Comment: This is the code that I am using:
`firebase: function(){
    cSites: {
        source: db.ref('users/').orderByChild('url').equalTo(this.$route.params.uid),
        readyCallback: function (){
            if(this.cSites.length ==0){
                this.$router.replace({name:'Home'})
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: This error is throwing because `router.replace` method only accepts `location, onComplete, onAbort` parameters. You're throwing in an object. Use `this.$router.replace('/[your-route-here')` instead.

Reference: https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-instance.html#methods

See `router.replace` method for clarification.

Comment: Might work, worth trying - but [Vue programatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html) also shows use of an object.

Comment: @izzy, I can't see a fault in the syntax you posted, except maybe try `this.$router.replace({name:'Home'});`

Comment: Ok, I think I have it. Try `firebase: function() { return { cSites:...` (plus a balancing bracket)

Comment: Perfect! that worked a treat. Thank you very much for your help!